# How to concatenate two CNN

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, fingerprint

I have two CNN based on MobileNet
Code (is the same for first and second CNN):

```
img_height, img_width = 224, 224
num_classes = 30
input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 3)

epochs = 1


base_model_fingerprint = MobileNet(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

x = base_model_fingerprint.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output_fingerprint = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

model_fingerprint = Model(inputs=base_model_fingerprint.input, outputs=output_fingerprint)


for layer in model_fingerprint.layers:
    layer._name = 'fingerprint_' + layer.name


for layer in base_model_fingerprint.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model_fingerprint.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen_fingerprint = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen_fingerprint = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator_fingerprint = train_datagen_fingerprint.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/giova/Desktop/CNN_FINGER_RESIZE/TRAIN',
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

test_generator_fingerprint = test_datagen_fingerprint.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/giova/Desktop/CNN_FINGER_RESIZE/TEST',
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')


reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.0001)
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)


history = model_fingerprint.fit(train_generator_fingerprint,
                                validation_data=test_generator_fingerprint,
                                epochs=epochs,
                                callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stop])


test_loss, test_acc = model_fingerprint.evaluate(test_generator_fingerprint, verbose=2)
print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

How can I create a third CNN for better accuracy?

I have tried to use model.save so I can use .h5 file but it doesn't work
the second CNN only changes the directory where it gets the input data from.

Update: I wrote this code but I can't solve the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model

# Carica i modelli delle due CNN
model1 = load_model('pesi_fingerprint.h5')
model2 = load_model('pesi_palmprint.h5')

# Rimuove l'ultimo livello di ciascuna CNN
model1.layers.pop()
model2.layers.pop()

# Imposta i layer delle due CNN come non trainabili
for layer in model1.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    layer._name = 'model1_' + layer.name
for layer in model2.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    layer._name = 'model2_' + layer.name

# Crea il nuovo modello concatenando le feature maps
concatenated = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([model1.layers[-1].output, model2.layers[-1].output])

x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((6, 5, 3))(concatenated) # aumenta le dimensioni
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(6, 5, 3))(x) # utilizza un kernel di convoluzione 3x3
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

# Crea il modello finale
model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input], outputs=output)

# Compila il modello
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Stampa la struttura del modello
model.summary()

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, # normalizza i valori dei pixel tra 0 e 1
    rotation_range=20, # ruota le immagini in modo casuale
    width_shift_range=0.2, # sposta le immagini in orizzontale in modo casuale
    height_shift_range=0.2, # sposta le immagini in verticale in modo casuale
    shear_range=0.2, # applica la deformazione di taglio alle immagini
    zoom_range=0.2, # applica lo zoom alle immagini
    horizontal_flip=True, # inverte le immagini in orizzontale in modo casuale
    fill_mode='nearest',
    target_size = (224,224) # riempie i pixel mancanti con il valore più vicino
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                  target_size=(224, 224))

# specifica il percorso della cartella che contiene i dati di training e di test
train_dir = 'C:\\Users\\giova\\Desktop\\MERGE CNN\\TRAIN'
test_dir = 'C:\\Users\\giova\\Desktop\\MERGE CNN\\TEST'

# imposta il numero di classi
num_classes = 30

# leggi i dati di training dalla cartella specificata
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

# leggi i dati di test dalla cartella specificata
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

# Addestramento del modello
# Addestramento del modello
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=test_generator)
```

ERROR:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "reshape" (type Reshape).

total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [60], output_shape = [6, 5, 3]

Call arguments received by layer "reshape" (type Reshape):
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 60), dtype=float32)

Answer (score 1):

The output shape of your concatenated model is `[60]` but you're trying to reshape it to `[6,5,3]` which is not possible since it changes the total size of the array eg : 6x5x3 != 60, try reshaping it to  `[6,5,2]` instead.